# In datasource, iterate over a list of strings, for each object in a main list

Tags: foreach, terraform, datasource

I would like to iterate on "dependencies list" of each object.

fgs.tfvars

```
admin_functions = [
    {
      name         = "function1"
      description  = "Function1 Description"
      memory       = 128
      timeout      = 90

      dependencies = [ 
        "esdk_obs_python",
        "provider",
        "common_finops"
      ]
    },
    {
      name         = "function2"
      memory       = 128
      timeout      = 90
      dependencies = [ 
        "esdk_obs_python"
      ]
    }
]
```

variables.tf

```
variable "admin_functions" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    description = optional(string)
    memory = number
    timeout = number
    user_data = optional(object({}))
    dependencies = optional(list(string))
  }))
}
```

I tried this. :

main.tf

```
locals {
  admin_functions_map = {
    for func in var.admin_functions : func.name => {
      dependencies = func.dependencies
    }
  }
}


data "flexibleengine_fgs_dependencies" "admin_functions" {
  for_each = local.admin_functions_map

  name = each.value.dependencies

}
```

But "name" expects a String and not a List of strings.
I can retrieve the first dependency with  `each.value.dependencies[0]` of course, but not all deps.

I tried with a for loop without success,  and tried too with a dynamic block to for_each again, but not working/not expected block in datasource.  (And I think dynamic here, is not a good idea)

If anyone have some advises / explanations ?  Maybe my map is not enough adapted to my case
Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, try name = each.key

Comment: Thanks,  but the for_each loop is over functions,  so each.key takes the name of my function.  (So,  datasource will search about a dependency named "function1"  for example)

Comment: You need to iterate keyed from the dependencies, and then the result will be a `data` keyed from each dependency. You cannot manage a keyless `data` here because of the type restriction on the `name` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I see.  
So because of data "name" restriction,  I can't iterate over dependencies  (except if there is a key by dependency ?)   
It could be possible if I define some maps/list definitions ?  Or you think not ?